# Why is the verb 選ばれる left in its stem form in the middle of this sentence?

Tags: grammar

しかし、アメリカではふつう、スポーツチームは腕｛うで｝で選｛えら｝ばれ,学業｛がくぎょう｝のコースは学力｛がくりょく｝によって選｛えら｝ばれます。
However, in America, sports teams are generally chosen by skill, and academic courses by ability.

Comment: **So many** questins are about 連〇〇 of verbs and adjectives.  I wonder how it is taught in Japanese-as-a-foreign-language because many learners seem to have zero idea about it.